# ab=lub{xy| x is in A and y is in B}

Tags: real-analysis

Is the lower upper bound of A (where A is a nonempty bounded set of real numbers) times the lower upper bound of B (where B is a nonempty bounded set of positive real numbers) equal to the lower upper bound of the set {xy | x is in A and y is in B}?

Answer (score 4):

It is not true, take $A = \{ -3 \}$, $B = \{ 2, 3\}$ and thus $AB = \{ -6, -9 \}$.
Then $$ \left( \sup_{a \in A} a \right) \left( \sup_{b \in B} b \right) = -3 \times 3 = -9 \neq - 6 = \sup_{x \in AB } x.$$

Comment: It's true for $A, B>0$ though.

Comment: Even for $A,B \ge 0$.

Comment: Yes, that's true :-$)$.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Take $A=\{-3,-1\}$ and $B=\{1,2\}$.

Then $\operatorname{lub}A=-1$ and $\operatorname{lub} B=2$ but $AB=\{-6,-1\}$ and $\operatorname{lub} AB=-1\ne (-1)(2)=\operatorname{lub}A\cdot\operatorname{lub}B$.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD, I meant intervals, but sets work as well.

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry! Feel free to remove my edit!!